# Get List of Permission set assigned to the user

Tags: apex, permission-sets

I want to get the list of permission set assigned to loggedin user.
And a conditional check one that.

If a user has 'TestABC' permission set assigned then boolean value should be true

I am using this approach

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> lstcurrentUserPerSet =    [   SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Name,AssigneeId
                                                                FROM PermissionSetAssignment
                                                                WHERE AssigneeId = :Userinfo.getUserId() ];
system.debug('##lstcurrentUserPerSet' + lstcurrentUserPerSet);

for (PermissionSetAssignment psa: lstcurrentUserPerSet)
{
    system.debug('##psa.PermissionSet.Name' + psa.PermissionSet.Name);
    if(psa.PermissionSet.Name.equals('TestABC'))
                Test = true;
    else
            Test = false;
}
```

I am not able to get any values in debug log. The list is not retreving any value it seems

Comment: Are you have assigned any PS to your user? Are you sure PS name is correct?

Comment: Yes i have assigned PS to user. Is the Name the API Name

Comment: Hmmmm, could you put there more debugs? User.Id for example. Because if you have PS assigned to user this query should return it...
Also is this code run in trigger or controller?

Comment: Its in controller.. ok fine will put more debug and check

Comment: It also could be help if you post controller code

Answer (score 7):

Is there a requirement that you need all the Permission sets to be queried for some other use? Or else if its just to check why don't we directly use this query

> SELECT count(Id) FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId =
>   :Userinfo.getUserId() AND PermissionSet.Name = '-permission set api name here-'

If result = 1 means the permission set is assigned for current user else if result = 0 means its not.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at your logic there, inside your for loop, you check to see if the name is equal, if it is then you set Test to true, else to false.

So if the user has 2 permission sets assigned, and the first one will set Test to true, the second will set it to false.

```
Boolean user_has_permission = false;
for ( PermissionSetAssignment psa : lstcurrentUserPerSet ) {
    System.debug('##psa.PermissionSet.Name' + psa.PermissionSet.Name);
    if ( psa.PermissionSet.Name.equals('TestABC') ) {
        user_has_permission = true;
    }
}
```

This will work, also ensure that you are using the API name of the Permission set in the case of TestABC

Answer (score 0):

may be useful to others if they looking SOQL or APEX to achieve this count requirement,

http://theblogreaders.com/many-list-users-assigned-salesforce-permissionset/

Thanks & Regards,
​​​​​​​Sakthivel Madesh